# TypeORM 0.2.21: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am not sure why I am getting the following error every time I try to sync with the database.

```
Error during schema synchronization:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined
    at /Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:594:66
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeEntityMetadataStep2 (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:594:37)
    at /Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:113:56
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:113:25)
    at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:66:111)
    at Connection.buildMetadatas (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/connection/Connection.ts:516:59)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/src/connection/Connection.ts:191:18)
    at step (/Users/geekox86/Documents/GitHub/OE Scoring/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
```

[Reproduction repo](https://github.com/geekox86/oe-scoring/tree/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that typeorm is trying to call is `build` from 
`typeorm/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts` and has the next signature:

`build(entityClasses?: Function[]): EntityMetadata[]) {}`

What it does is it builds a complete entity metadatas for the given entity classes and compute parent entity metadatas for table inheritance.

What that tells me is that there's something wrong with the way you're trying to create the relations between entities. You might need to check relations one by one by removing it temporarily until you find which one is creating the problem.

Comment: I was missing @ChildEntity of an abstract class in the middle of class inheritance chain